# Do I really need to use protoypes for this in javascript? (Practical example)

Tags: javascript

## Can this be written **without** complexing things with prototypes?

**Why?** The current code does what I want, but it bothers me how trixy it is to follow and how error prone it is, also seems to be performance wasting since things are duplicated.

**Aim?** The more I spend using prototype and this I get the sense the code would be simpler and more to the point if this was not the case.

> Especially if the this-functions in SystemBlueprint can be rewritten to take an instance as argument instead. And if object Function Log() and Out could just be plain objects somehow? How can Log or Out be extracted outside of SystemBuilder?

### Full code in Jsbin

> https://jsbin.com/pigosijaxo/edit?js,console (Updated)

```
// Local for each System object
var SystemData = {
    name: '?',
    id: 1,
    actions: [],
    destinations: []
}

// Variables shared among all Systems
const SystemShare = {
    global: 1
}

// this-Functions shared among all Systems
function SystemBlueprint() {}
SystemBlueprint.prototype = {
    run() {
        var length = this.actions.length
        for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            var result = this.actions[i](arguments, this)
            if (result && this.destinations.length > 0) {
                for (var n = 0; n < this.destinations.length; n++) {
                    this.destinations[n].call(null, result)
                }
            }
        }
    },
    does(algorithm) {
        this.actions.push(algorithm)
        return this
    },
    random(min, max) {
        return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
    }
}

function SystemBuilder(name) {
    // copy shared methods
    var system = Object.create(SystemBlueprint.prototype)
    Object.assign(system, JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(SystemData))) //deep copy

    system.name = name
    system.id = SystemShare.global++

    function Log() {}
    Log.prototype.local = () => console.log('fields: ' + JSON.stringify(Object.keys(system))),
    system.log = new Log()

    function Out(){}
    Out.prototype.into = (destination) => {
        system.destinations.push(destination)
        return system
    }
    system.out = new Out()

    system.trigger = {}
    function OnEvent(trigger){
        if(trigger === undefined) return
        trigger.call(null, system.run.bind(system))
        return system
    }
    system.trigger.on = new OnEvent()
    return system
}

var system = new SystemBuilder()
system.my = 'Testing'
system.log.local()
system.does( () => 'printing output...')
system.out.into(console.log)
system.run()
```

Comment: I tried something almost like that but that did not copy the full object, which made changes depending on the last "call", can you give/link what you mean? [Edit ok seems comment above disappeared]

Comment: I am really confused by your code but you should look into the `Function.prototype.bind` method. That way you can bind your this objects and parameter to existing functions. https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind

Comment: I kinda want to not have to use bind, or this if possible. Any suggestions how I can un-confuse my code? I agree it is confusing, I'm not liking it myself, hence the question :D

Comment: I can understand that you don't want to but it is more structured. For example the `Log`: consider the local function to be `function _local(system){console.log([...])}` you can then bind your current system by `system.log = {local: _local.bind(this, system)}`. Now you only have to call `system.log.local()` and the system parameter is already bound. This way you can pull out the `Out` and `Log` functions out of the factory.

Comment: Okey, I like that, Implemented in answer below how I think you meant. I can see how moving the function outside is straight-forward now.

Comment: Oh and you shouldn't call the `SystemBuilder` with `new`. Just `var system = SystemBuilder()` ;)

Answer (score 0):

Partial Answer, implementation from comment suggestion by @Bellian, a bit on the way for sure, thanks!

**Where?** Inside function SystemBuilder(...):

### Instead of

```
function Log() {}
Log.prototype.local = () => console.log('fields: ' + JSON.stringify(Object.keys(system))),
system.log = new Log()
```

### Do this

```
function _local(system){
  console.log('fields: ' + JSON.stringify(Object.keys(system)))
}
system.log = {local: _local.bind(this, system)}
```

Comment: Jea right. You now can create the `_local` function outside the SystemBuilder. That way the function will only be created once but bound multiple times. This pattern can be applied on the `Log`, `Out` and `OnEvent` functions.